# Keyboard functionality of iPhone in Telegram webview application

Tags: css, iphone, webview, telegram, progressive-web-apps

I have a Telegram webview application that opens my website. There is a text input area (standard input) on this site. When focused on this input via iPhone, the webview page stops scrolling and becomes «stuck»

This issue can be resolved by tapping the screen again to hide the keyboard. Everything works fine in the browser (scrolls normally). The problem seems to only occur on iPhones, as everything works fine on Android devices